# Installed elementary OS need help with multiple issues (first time Linux user)

Tags: hardware

Issues since install:
My new Lenovo yoga 7i is working harder with the new linux OS. But it comes in spurts.
Track pad does not work. Sound output unable to figure out. Sound input (mic) unable to figure out. I also have a touch screen and fingerprint scanner. Both I can live without, but if I can get direction on the initial issues, and also some guidance on installing .deb files using the command prompt. I am very new at this, just trying to see if I can make Linux work.

Also if someone could provide a link to instructions on how to safely remove the additional OS from my computer that would be great. I am not at that point yet, and Can still do a dual boot, but I wouldn't mind cleaning up the entire boot process to make it look cleaner if someone has advice on that for this version of linux with windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Just use the dual boot to start with, Just google how to use the elementary OS on a dual boot with windows 10, I had Yoga until November never had an issue you described:

https://thelinuxuser.com/dual-boot-elementary-os/

eOS - Touch screen never worked and Fingerprint doesn't work also so don't bother about it much.

Installing deb file just install like this using terminal:

> dpkg -i file.deb

When install new eOS just download the latest ISO Yoga 7i is a little old device so you should not have an issue with any drivers.